# Exclude entries from SELECT COUNT

Tags: mysql, mysql-5

I'm new to MySQL and I have a problem with one task.
I have a table like this:

```
+------------+------------+-------------+
| code       | name       | location    |
+------------+------------+-------------+
|          1 |          a |           x |
|          2 |          a |           x |
|          3 |          a |           x |
|          4 |          a |           x |
|          5 |          b |           x |
|          6 |          b |           x |
|          7 |          c |           x |
|          8 |          c |           x |
|          9 |          c |           x |
|         10 |          c |           x |
+------------+------------+-------------+
```

I want to count all the codes that have location X but exclude all if in at least one the location is set to Y.

So far I managed to do this:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS  `how much` ,  `name` ,  `location` 
FROM  table
WHERE  `location` =  'x' AND `location` <> 'y'
GROUP BY   `name`
ORDER BY   `name`
```

which gave me

```
+------------+------------+-------------+
| how much   | name       | location    |
+------------+------------+-------------+
|          4 |          a |           x |
|          2 |          b |           x |
|          4 |          c |           x |
+------------+------------+-------------+
```

As soon as I change the location on code 1 from x to y
it changes to:

```
+------------+------------+-------------+
| how much   | name       | location    |
+------------+------------+-------------+
|          3 |          a |           x |
|          2 |          b |           x |
|          4 |          c |           x |
+------------+------------+-------------+
```

but I need to exclude it:

```
+------------+------------+-------------+
| how much   | name       | location    |
+------------+------------+-------------+
|          2 |          b |           x |
|          4 |          c |           x |
+------------+------------+-------------+
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick.

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS  `how much` ,  `name` ,  `location` 
FROM  table
WHERE  name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM table WHERE location = 'y')
GROUP BY   `name`
ORDER BY   `name`
```

The idea behind this is : we are counting the number of `name` but we have to exclude rows of `name` where in ANOTHER row there is `location = 'y'`.

If you do WHERE `location <> 'y'`, you just exclude the line including `location = 'y'` but the others rows with `location = 'x'` are still there and used in count(*).

So, the goal is to exclude ALL names where a minimum of one row has `location = 'y'`. This is why we do `name NOT IN (...)`.

The part between the brackets select all `name` where `location = 'y'`. This outputs all names we want to exclude from our COUNT(*). We just have to exclude all these results from our query.

That's all folks !